# How to manually specify syntax highlighting for a specific extension in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I am editing some files with the extension '.ctp'. Although these files are perfectly valid PHP files, Eclipse doesn't seem to know that and refuses to do any syntax highlighting with them.

How can I manually instruct it to use PHP syntax coloring for '.ctp' files? Is there even a way to do that?

Comment: you may need to restart eclipse to take effect

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In *Preferences*, go to **General** -> **Content Types**. Unfold **Text**, then go to **PHP Content Type**. Click *Add* and input **.ctp*. Then apply your changes.

You may need to restart eclipse to take effect.

Comment: On my machine it wasn't necessary to restart Eclipse just close and reopen the file.

Comment: and, funny enough, restarting Eclipse did nothing for me -- I _had_ to open/close the file for it to take effect.

Comment: You can find `Preferences` under `Window`, for those looking.