# Syntax highlighting of Vagrantfiles using Eclipse: Ruby Development Tools

Tags: ruby, eclipse, chef-infra, vagrant

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the Eclipse: Ruby Development Tools to recognize a file without a .rb extension as ruby and highlight it accordingly. I'm using Eclipse 4.2.1 and RDT 4.0.0.

My use case is specifically with Chef cookbooks and Vagrantfile definitions which use ruby as the syntax.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may try out some modelines:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1985247/170230

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think Eclipse honors modelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably work, you just have to adapt it to use Ruby instead. [Eclipse syntax highlighting: trying to specify it for a new file extension, and it's not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524366/eclipse-syntax-highlighting-trying-to-specify-it-for-a-new-file-extension-and)